# "message": "User.findOne(...).lean.exec is not a function" } in MERN course by YouTube

Tags: node.js, mern

This line of code in userController.js has error:

```
const duplicate = await User.findOne({ username }).lean.exec();
```

It in Postman goes to
"message": "User.findOne(...).lean.exec is not a function" }

Just replace code above with this (I forgot brackets..):

```
// Check if user exists, if there is duplicates
const duplicate = await User.findOne({ username }).lean().exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in absense of brackets after .lean

It should be .lean().exec()